# How do I fix (ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtCore) for a standalone python application in VS Code using qgis.core?

Tags: python, dll, pyqt5, qgis, pyqgis

**My Tools for the Project**
I am using Python 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]
I am using QGIS 3.28.2
IDE: VS Code
I followed the guide on locate press.

**The Want**
I am trying to take in large orthophotos (>10GB), compress them (<250MB), then display them using the QGIS GUI, and finally manipulate them using some masking and extraction tools.

What I need is for someone to tell me how to setup my environment and IDE to import the QGIS library.

**The Error Code**

```
PS C:\Users\pkmos\OneDrive\Desktop\DIYGIS> & "C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.28.0/bin/python.exe" c:/Users/pkmos/OneDrive/Desktop/DIYGIS/appl.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\pkmos\OneDrive\Desktop\DIYGIS\appl.py", line 2, in <module>
    import qgis
  File "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.0\apps\qgis\python\qgis\__init__.py", line 78, in <module>
    from qgis.PyQt import QtCore
  File "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.0\apps\qgis\python\qgis\PyQt\QtCore.py", line 24, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtCore: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

**The Script**

```
import sys
import qgis

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel

def window():
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   widget = QWidget()

   textLabel = QLabel(widget)
   textLabel.setText("Hello World!")
   textLabel.move(110,85)

   widget.setGeometry(50,50,320,200)
   widget.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 Example")
   widget.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   window()
```

**The Environment**

```
PATH=$PATH;"C:\OSGeo4W\bin";"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis";"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\bin";"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Qt5\bin";"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\Scripts";"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Qt5\bin"
PYTHONPATH="C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\python"
PYTHONHOME="C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39"
```

**The Workspace**

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "name": "app",
            "path": "C:/Users/pkmos/OneDrive/Desktop/DIYGIS"
        }
    ]
}
```

**The Progress**
I have figured out the compression using the GDAL library. However the QGIS GUI will not open in my standalone application. I have tried adding many different folders to the system environment variables. I will post some pictures to show you what we are dealing with. I have checked to make sure I am using the correct versions of QGIS and Python.

[Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQDtH.png)

[PYTHONPATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLFOt.png)

[Folder 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JuKL.png)

[Folder 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFGNl.png)

[Folder 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlbUF.png)

[Folder 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6dWC.png)

[Folder 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg7LE.png)

**The Help I Need**
My skills are very small :(. If someone could point me in the right direction to setup my IDE VS Code to import the qgis.core library I think I can build the rest of the program. How do I create the right environment to make a standalone python application that uses QGIS GUI?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I probably worked on this problem solo for 5 hours before posting here and then I think I just found the answer.

I created a bat file with this code and ran it and then opened my original appl.py file and ran that and it opened the GUI window with hello world.

```
@echo off
path %PATH%;C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.0\bin
path %PATH%;C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.0\apps\grass\grass78\lib
path %PATH%;C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.0\apps\Qt5\bin
path %PATH%;C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.0\apps\Python39\Scripts

set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.0\apps\qgis\python
set PYTHONHOME=C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.0\apps\Python39

start "VisualStudioCode for QGIS" /B "C:\Users\pkmos\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" %*
```

So if anyone still wants to comment and tell me all the things I was doing wrong and how I have no idea what environment variables are, please do.

I hope this helps other noobs like me!